# Firebase get the reference of the child of a child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

As you see each post has a different **Id** (the user id who posted) I'm trying to get the reference of this child **fx3RqooRMOVRaQHGas4OWQnFK593** for example so the database reference will be like this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child("fx3RqooRMOVRaQHGas4OWQnFK593");
```

But what I want is to get that reference dynamically for each post Id.

Comment: Assuming you are using FirbaseAuth too, you can dynamically get the user ID using FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()

Comment: This will only work with the current user posts only, i'm trying to display all the posts using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, this one takes a reference and display all posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 option.

1. if u want to download one single post then u have to use your custom postId. you can't use pushId(). So that you will know which post u want to download and show.

how to make custom id

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts")
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   HashMap<String, Object> post = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                   total= post.size();

                }
      }
```

and then create custom id

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child("post"+total).setValue(YourValue);
```

option 2.

Simply download all post from the post node because u have to ..

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        //here is your every post 
                        String key = snapshot.getKey(); 
                        Object value = snapshot.getValue();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Bonus 
if u want to show post of a particular user. (I am assuming that)
u can store the push key inside the user object in a string arrylist. then just call them one by one ...

happy coding :) :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("Posts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
postsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be all those keys.

Comment: my FirebaseRecyclerAdapter takes 4 parameters one is a database reference , so i must store it in a DatabaseReference  variable then use it.

Comment: So, feel free to do it. The above code is showing you exact the way in which you can query your Firbease database and get the desired keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Posts")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String key = snapshot.getKey(); // key here
                            Object value = snapshot.getValue(); // value here
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```